# Erro Requisição Ajax e versões jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estou com um problema para entender e resolver um problema com uma requisição *Ajax* que preciso fazer. Segue abaixo uma lista de sequência do assunto que irei dizer:

- Explicar o que eu preciso;
- Explicar o que quero fazer;
- Mostrar como está atualmente;
- Apresentar as soluções que já tentei;

Primeiro:
Estou desenvolvendo um site de viagens, onde este site possui uma *navbar*, nesta navbar há um menu chamado 'Informações'.
Acontece que tenho uma plataforma/sistema que o usuário acessa e cria um artigo que é inserido como um item do Menu *Dropdown* toda vez que ele cria um artigo novo (o menu possui um *while*).

O que eu preciso e quero fazer é: toda vez  que o visitante clicar em um desses itens/menus do Menu Drop, ele abra um modal do Bootstrap com a informação do artigo feito pelo cliente.
Certo?

Essa é a ideia.
Bom, o que eu preciso é apenas pegar do banco de dados essa informação (o que já fiz) e apresenta-lo em uma página .php (o que também já fiz, chame-se response.php). Essa página apenas exibe o texto escrito pelo usuário sem estilo nenhum (feito já no modal ou na hora da criação do artigo). O que me resta fazer é chamar essa página via Javascript com o *jQuery* e *Ajax* (que é o que eu quero fazer). No entanto esse é o meu problema e eu não sei ao certo onde preciso ver. Segue abaixo

Ponto de Problema:
1º: a versão do *jQuery* utilizada é 2.1.4 (outro dev trabalhou antes e ficou com esse), e eu testei usar uma versão mais atual. O resultado foi que funcionou a requisição só que outros plugins que usam *jQuery* pararam de funcionar ou não eram reconhecidos.

2º: Há 2 tipos de *links* para o site: 1 é com o domínio proprio aqui *(www.dominioproprio.com/)*. Quando é assim, a requisição aparece normalmente, no entanto quando acesso o site real do cliente (*www.sitedocliente.com.br*), a requisição quando é feita, ela trava e não vai para o Success.

3º: Quando tento usar o *link* manualmente da requisição:

www.sitedocliente.com.br/response?page_id=123

o resultado é:

> The requested URL /response was not found on this server.

Isso já está me tirando do serio e já comparei com outras utilizações de ajax minha e está ok.

Segue abaixo algumas informações da requisição no JS:

```
$("[data-page-id]").click(function(){
let page_id=$(this).attr("data-page-id");
let response=$(".response-content");
response.html("<div class='text-center'><i class='fa fas fa-cog fa-spin fa-5x'></i>");
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:link+"/response?page_id="+page_id,
        type:'GET',
        success:function(data){
        $(response).html(data);
        }
    });
},200); 
});
```

E agora temos também como está no  `HTML` a exibição desse atributo `data-page-id`:
Eu coloquei de forma bem rudimentar porque não estou com acesso ao server mas reescrevi para entenderem:

```
<ul>
        <?php 
            while($pagina = $paginas->fetch_object()){
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_response" data-page-id="<?= $pagina->id ?>"></a>
                </li>
            }
        ?>
</ul>
```

Esta variável `$pagina` recebe os resultados da tabela PAGINAS que contém os artigos escritos pelo cliente (artigo soa forte, é mais uma mensagem num modal ^^ ).

Além disso, `$pagina->id` está no `data-page-id` pois essa será a referencia de cada LI criada.

Infos:

`link` é uma variável javascript que está recebendo  o site atual;

Essa é o código da pagina response que apresenta o artigo no modal

```
<?php
    $_GET = $db->Escapar($_GET);

    if(!isset($_GET['page_id'])) 
        die("ID não encontrado");

    $page_id = $_GET['page_id'];

    $pagina = $db->Executar("SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE adm_id=$adm_id AND id=$page_id");

    if($pagina->num_rows == 0) die("ID não encontrado");
        $pagina = $pagina->fetch_object();

?>

<!--<img style="margin: 0 auto; max-height: 250px; display: block" src="<?=$pagina->avatar?>"/>-->
<br>
<?=$pagina->pagina; ?>
```

Essas informações são suficientes? Me digam o que acham e como posso corrigir.

Grato!

EDIT 1: Antes que me perguntem ou não haha... O *URI* `/response?page_id=01` nao tem o `.php` por causa dessa gracinha aqui:

```
if($url[0] == "response") {
    include "response.php";
    exit();
}
```

EDIT 2: Agora que já informei o suficiente para entender o funcionamento e que ao meu ver está correto, preciso saber porque a requisição não consegue acessar a partir do site do cliente, apenas do meu servidor, sendo que está tudo igual e carregado lá?

Comment: RESPONSE é um diretório ou um arquivo?

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho um arquivo php

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho é ele que quero chamar no modal e cada um com seu id especifico? entende;

Comment: Você fez alguma configuração no htaccess? Caso naõ, da forma que está, o servidor está tentando localizar arquivo index.php no diretório response. Tente dessa forma: www.sitedocliente.com.br/response.php?page_id=123

Comment: O site não tem um '.htaccess'
Faz assim, pra tu entender:
acesse esse link e veja as URL

Uma é do meu dominio e outro do cliente.

H -> https://goo.gl/ghC8A7
Site Cliente ->https://goo.gl/K1qNDF

Quero deixar assim:

-> https://goo.gl/YTw5oj

Eu quero que o response seja encontrado para que a requisicao ajax funcione

Comment: Veja os links somente daqui a meia hora pq o server ta off agora hehe

Comment: poderia postar o seu javascript, por favor?

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho Qual? Aquele chamando a requisição? Já está no corpo da pergunta, senão for, me informe que posto!

Comment: o código postado está repetido, tem 2 do PHP

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho me desculpe, não sei se foi a edição do pessoal ou erro meu msm, olhe novamente. Está corrigido!

Comment: pq você está utilizando o setTimeout na chamada do ajax? A variável "link" já foi definida anteriormente? Se a sua varíavel "link" não é global, ela precisa ser definida no escopo da função click. Caso ela não exista, o ajax está tentando localizar "/response" dentro do seu próprio servidor.

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho 
Sim, a variavel link é global. Ela está sendo chamada corretamente, acontece que ele não está achando o /response dentro do servidor. E aí que está o problema. Não sei porque ele não está sendo encontrado. Tudo foi carregado, igual a outros sites que já usei o mesmo esquema. Lembra dos links que passei ontem, de uma olha e me diz o que acha.

- Primeiro link é do servidor interno (funciona normalmente)
- Segundo link é do site do cliente (não está sendo chamado)
- Terceiro link é de um site do cliente e que está funcionando

Comment: o erro retornado é que response.php não existe para o endereço que você está passando: http://duartviagens.com.br/response?page_id=122. O caminho correto onde está localizado o response.php é: http://duartviagens.com.br/sistema/temas/duart-viagens/response

Comment: Entretanto, sem os acessos ao ftp pra entender a estruturação do seu website fica complicado ajudá-lo. O que eu faria também, seria retirar todas essas variáveis no formato oculto do seu código fonte.

Comment: conseguiu arrumar? Se sim, me informe para oficializar a resposta, por favor. Obrigado

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho Mano, muuito obrigado pela atenção aí, ok? Como único comentarista aqui, haha. Consegui resolver seguindo aí o processo de dicas que fostes me dando. Eu não costumo mexer nessas partes do servidor, que é outro dev que faz mas dessa vez não teve jeito. Vlw pela ajuda. O caso era que a variavel "link" do javascript estava recebendo de um 'input' um 'value' que era a variavel em PHP $LinkPrincipal que continha o link atual do site (através dos scripts pré-definidos do php) mas era apenas o site 'dominioproprio.com' e nao o do 'sitedocliente'; ^^ Vlw msm